# Как в Битриксе обратиться к css классу и изменить значение его свойства с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день! Есть следующий css код

```css
.wrapper,
.wrapper ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

И html код:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/inf/1.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/info/2.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/info/3.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Как обратиться к css классу и изменить значение свойство margin с помощью js?

Answer (score 0):

Через querySelector обращаешься, через style задаешь.

```js
document.querySelector('.class').style.margin = 'value' + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

JS и Jquery работают независимо от CMS, главное подгрузить скрипт (встроить в шаблон, например).

```
$(".wrapper").css("margin", "5px");
```